# Matlab, Using a loop to read all files in a folder using xlsread

Tags: matlab

I have a set of files in a folder. the file names are listed as : Month_1, Month_2, .... I want to get the data through a loop that i don't have to change the file name every single time. 
I tried for example:

```
for (i=1:1:53)
    path(i) = strcat('C:\Users\Desktop\Diagramm\','\Month_', i);
    aa=xlsread(path(i));
    ...
end;
```

but it isn't working. 
I would appreciate any help.

Comment: `path(i)` holds the entire string? Are you sure? I don't think so. It can hold only 1 character. Maybe you want `path{i}`.

Comment: Ha, just saw your comment, indeed should be marked as duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
files=dir('*.xls');
for i=length(files(:,1))
    aa=xlsread(files(i).name);
    % If you want to store data from each file separately with a new name
    eval(sprintf('Month%d=data ;',i));
end
```

Comment: Cool! When you have a time please accept an answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your files are located in the outdir.

```
files=dir(outdir);

for i=1:size(files,1)
   % do stuff with files(i)
end
```